# Date only on some content

Tags: joomla-3.x

I would like to show the dates of the articles *on the main site* (because the articles are news), and don't want to show the dates in all other menus (because the other content is static).

Unfortunately I only can find a standard-option to activate or deactivate all at a time.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: If an answer provides a solution to your problem it's good etiquette, and good manners, to mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the default setting on a per-category basis via the menu manager. E.g.:

main menu > News (or whatever your category is called) > options > date.

[image]